# Onclick remove function issue in GSP

Tags: javascript, jquery, grails, gsp

In GSP I have written code like this which will display list of files:

```
       <g:each in="${fileList}" var="file">
            <div>
                <a href="#" onclick="remove('${file.attachmentId}')"> 
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></a> 
                <a href="/forms/landing/attachment/${file.attachmentId}" >${file.name}</a> 
                </br>
            </div>
        </g:each>
```

And my javaScript code is:

```
function remove(attachmentId) {
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('.glyphicon-remove').click ( function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).parent().parent().remove();

            $.ajax({
                       url: "${g.createLink(controller: "landing", action: "deleteSelectedFile")}",
                        data: {
                                attachmentId: attachmentId
                        },
                        success: function(data){
                                alert("Success");
                        }

                   });

             });
        });

    }
```

I am calling onclick remove() function passing the selected attachmentId as the parameter. For the first time only after double click its deleting the file.

Why only after double click its deleting the file for the first time?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Note: Application is running in IE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since this tag

```
<div id="remove">
```

is present inside the g:each tag, you are creating multiple ids in the same page. When the function remove() is being called, it is removing all the divs where it finds "remove" as an id. Make each id unique and that would solve the problem

Since you are using jQuery, try using this code. This will eliminate the use of unique id.

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.glyphicon-remove').click ( function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                $(this).parent().parent().remove();
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Hi @elixir but here the problem is: Let us consider i have 3 files. If I try to delete 3rd file second file is getting deleted. But not all.

Comment: Hi @elixir I understood my basic fault, that there should not be multiple elements with same ID. But now I made it as class. How to delete the specific element on which onclick is called.

Comment: Hi @elixir, the updated solution is taking out complete gsp. Now the complete page is removed. I think we are nearing to the solution. But unfortunately the updated solution didn't work out for me.

Comment: Hi @elixir I updated the answer, which works perfectly fine for my requirement. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hi @elixir, the file is getting removed from UI, but its actually not getting removed from the back end!

Comment: you need need to send a get or post (preferred) request to some controller/action so the actual files are deleted in the backend. you can do this by sending an ajax request and remove the div only when you receive a success message back from the server.

Comment: Hi @elixir, thank you so much your answer exactly matches my requirement.  Now the only issue is for the first time only upon double click its deleting the file. Can you help me out please.

Comment: i am not sure how you have implemented your server side code. you should post your server side codes for us to offer any help. looks like @Nathan has already directed you in the right direction

Answer (score 1):

Having duplicate ID values will cause problems with any DOM (Document Object Model) manipulation. Your question is how do I properly delete files from the server through a browser interface. Groovy can leverage Apache Ant for file manipulation and by using the AntBuilder class you simplify a variety of tasks associated with file manipulation.

Please read [this entry in the Groovy docs](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/ant-builder.html) about using the AntBuilder. 
And check out The Service Layer in the Grails documentation to understand how to work with Services. Service oriented architecture will help you keep your controller and domain classes very conventional and allow you to create services that can be called by multiple controllers for more specific functions. If you followed the convention for Grails, your controller will already have a `delete` function. Instead of adding a `deleteFile` method in that controller, call a service which defines `deleteFile`.

Your code to delete will look something like the following:

[Create a service for file manipulation](https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/guide/services.html) (for example FileService.groovy under the services part of your project). Here you can place classes and functions to delete, add, zip text files. Leverage groovy's built in support for ApacheAnt by calling the AntBuilder utility.

```
//This is to instantiate an instance of the AntBuilder class.
import groovy.util.AntBuilder

class FileRemover {
    def ant = new AntBuilder() 


    //Define the file, which you will want to pass a value from the page. 
    //You may need to tweak the file path to match your project structure. 

    def file = new File(ant.project.baseDir,
                    "/forms/landing/attachment/${file.attachmentId}")
    def fileName = file.name.toString()
    assert file.exists()

    //Function to remove file
    def fileRemover = file.delete()

    //Provide messaging to let the user know the file has been removed
    println 'File ' + {fileName} + ' has been removed.'
}
```

This code will need a few personalization changes to get working in your project but by reading the documentation linked in the answer and following the basic idea of the code, you should be able to create an action that deletes files and can be called from the GSP page.

**Updated:**

To see a simple example of a file manager written in Grails, read [this blog post](https://fbflex.wordpress.com/2008/11/26/a-simple-grails-controller-for-file-management/) by Thomas Lin.

Comment: Hi @Nathan, I am getting issues wrt the groovy code changes. I am unable to achieve success both on front end and back end. Can we not completely take care of this issue by JavaScript itself.

Comment: You will need to perform the deletion from the server via server side code.   In Grails this can be achieved with java code in the controller or service. Manipulating the DOM via javascript is a client side operation. I have updated my answer to link to a nice tutorial on file management in Grails.

Answer (score 0):

In GSP:

```
<g:each in="${fileList}" var="file">
            <div>
                <a href="#" onclick="remove('${file.attachmentId}', this)">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></a> 
                <a href="/forms/landing/attachment/${file.attachmentId}" >${file.name}</a> 
                </br>
            </div>
        </g:each>
```

In JavaScript:

```
function remove(attachmentId, elem) {
    $(elem).parent().remove();
    $.ajax({
       url: "${g.createLink(controller: "landing", action: "deleteSelectedFile")}",
       data: {attachmentId: attachmentId},
        success: function(data){
            alert("Success");
        }

   });
}
```

This will perfectly solve the problem.